# Magento 2 - Redirect to "My account" page when clicking "Addressbook"

Tags: magento, redirect, addressbook, magento2

We just launched a Magento 2.0.4 store, but we're experiencing the issue described below. Hopefully someone can help us fix this.

**When a customer is logged in in our store and clicks on "Addressbook" on the "My account" page, he gets redirected back to the "My Account" page.**

The redirect order is as follows and all redirects are 302's (Moved Temporarily):

- /customer/account/ --> /customer/address/new (as expected because this customer has not created any address yet)
- /customer/address/new --> /customer/account/login/ **(herein lies the issue, we would like to see the "Add New Address" page)**
- /customer/account/login --> /customer/account (as expected)

**Notes:** Our store is running on HTTPS and a custom made theme which is based on the default Luma theme. We also have another Magento 2.0.4 store running on the same server with the same hosting provider and the issue is not present here. [You can try it yourself here.](https://dampershop.nl)

**What we tried:**

- Disabling all custom modules
- Removing all custom language files (i18n folder)
- Disabling SEO URLs

[Here is a screenshot which shows the redirect order in the Chrome Developer Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl2bl.png)

Answer (score 0):

We have found the solution. Apparently a module was in fact still causing the problem: Mirasvit_Core. Disabling the module and deploying static content again fixed the issue.

Thanks for reading and I hope this helps anyone else having this problem.